# Fan Error on Lenovo R61

Tags: boot, laptop, fan, cooling, thinkpad

**Problem**

Since the last two days, my Lenovo R61 is giving me a "Fan Error" message during boot, after showing which, it powers down.

It does so for 3-4 boot attempts, and after a bit of tapping and such human treatment, in the 6th or so attempt, it luckily starts.

**Question**

1. Why is this happening ?
2. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why? Well.. its lifetime is over, thats all.
2) Find a [service](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-44986&sitestyle=Lenovo) and if you are lucky, you can get it fixed right there, for cheap. It's much better than you start fixing it, trust me. It's not that easy. (Also, the fan inside is a special one, you can't just get one to replace it. Aaand you need to disassemble it quite much to replace it.)

Comment: okk. But well its been just 2 years, it went out pretty quickly?
and plus since this is a specialised fan, it may come for a lot more than what the regular fans come for?

Comment: Oh I found you something! http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewforum.php?f=47 (I found some topics about fan problems. If its not in warranty, you may find some cool tips.)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same laptop and i was experiencing the same problem......Keep Hitting the escape key when "Fan error" pops up. But make sure you get your fan fixed as soon as possible otherwise you might damage your core due to overheating!